# Side by Side Translations on Page without Table

Tags: javascript, html, css, typography

I'd like to be able to put a text and it's translation side by side, in such a way that the original and the translation are each a single run of text (that could be highlighted, for copy-paste, etc), but without the two texts getting more than a line or two out of sync.

This sort of thing is usually done with tables - a column for each language and a row for each paragraph, verse or line. The problem, then, is that you can't highlight down one column without grabbing-in the adjacent column. Also, the markup becomes a disaster.

What I'd like to do is have the markup look something like:

```
<div id="Pig-Latin">
  <p id="pl-1">Isthay isay inelay unway.</p>
  <p id="pl-2">Igpay Atinlay isay ardhay anguagelay.</p>
</div>

<div id="English">
  <p id="en-1">Translation of line one.</p>    
  <p id="en-2">Translation of line two.</p>
</div>
```

Have the two languages in columns side by side, and use something (javascript, I imagine) to make sure that en-1 and pl-1 line up, etc...

Actually -- it would be even better if it was markers that didn't wrap any text:

`<a id="en-1"></a> This is line one....`
(Of if there is some html element I don't know about that would be more semantically appropriate...)

On a smaller screen, or if the user so desired, one column or the other could be shown alone.

Other question of a similar nature have yielded the "use tables" answer, which I would like not to do - as I mention.

Comment: So far the only idea I've had myself is to put each verse in a `<p>` and then use JS to compare the height of each pair, and then then make the smaller of the two equal to the larger of the two.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, your situation needs CSS and not JavaScript. You can use the following div based HTML for your purpose(since you do not want to use tables, which is a good thing btw)

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="main-col">  Some original text may be in English  </div>
   <div class="trans-col">  Translation comes in this div </div>
</div>
```

You can reputedly use this HTML for each row.

In the CSS, you will have 3 classes

```
.row{
  width:100%;
}

.main-col{
   width:50%;
}
.trans-col{
   width:50%;
}
```

This CSS will give 50% width of a row to each main text and your translation. If you are aware of float in CSS trying using floating divs for each column so that you can stack them up properly when user shrinks the browser window.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. But...

This has all the same problems as using tables.
I don't want the two texts smashed together, back and forth in the markup. I want one run of the entirety of each text, in side by side columns, with the vertical placement of the contents to shift so that parallel lines are next to each other.